# Spreadsheetgear - edit comment

Tags: spreadsheetgear

In Spreadsheetgear, I can right-click on a cell and select "edit comment".
I'd like to do the same from code. But I see only an "IRange.AddComment" method, no "EditComment"...
Is it possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Editing a cell comment in the manner you are speaking of is purely a UI-related task (presumably from one of the [WorkbookView](http://www.spreadsheetgear.com/support/help/spreadsheetgear.net.7.0/#SpreadsheetGear2012.Windows.Forms~SpreadsheetGear.Windows.Forms.WorkbookView_members.html) controls) and so you won't see any "EditComment" sort of API in SpreadsheetGear's "core" API such as the [IRange](http://www.spreadsheetgear.com/support/help/spreadsheetgear.net.7.0/#SpreadsheetGear2012.Core~SpreadsheetGear.IRange_members.html) interface.

Instead, you would need to call [BeginEdit](http://www.spreadsheetgear.com/support/help/spreadsheetgear.net.7.0/#SpreadsheetGear2012.Windows.Forms~SpreadsheetGear.Windows.Forms.WorkbookView~BeginEdit.html)() method on the WorkbookView while the desired comment shape is selected.  Below is some sample code that demonstrates this:

```
// Assuming there's a comment in A1...
SpreadsheetGear.IComment comment = workbookView.ActiveWorksheet.Cells["A1"].Comment;

// Ensure the comment is visible.
comment.Visible = true;

// Select it.
comment.Shape.Select(true);

// Tell the WorkbookView to enable "edit mode" on the currently selected
// item, which in this case we know is the cell comment in A1.
workbookView.BeginEdit();
```